# Knowing the Status of FileVault via fdesetup when encryption is paused

Tags: cocoa, encryption, osx-yosemite, filevault

My Application detects encryption on the Mac, and shows the status accordingly. 
Example: Encryption is in progress: 20% complete"

I am achieving this by reading the output of `fdesetup status` command. In Yosemite, when the power plus is unplugged from a Macbook pro, the encryption pauses. And  `fdesetup status` gives the appropriate info, which says the encryption is paused.

But while decrypting, it just says "file vault is off" when the decryption is paused.

Is there anyway to figure out of decryption is paused?